# Notepad++ regex to remove spaces between specific characters but not ALL spaces

Tags: regex, notepad++

I thought my regex skills were strong, but I'm getting crushed.

I have several lines in thsi format

```
Time: 105 0 0
Time: 88  0 1
Time: 44  1 1
Time: 64  1 0
```

I want theses to turn into this:

```
Time: 105 thread00
Time: 88  thread01
Time: 44  thread11
Time: 64  thread10
```

I can match the `[0-9][ ][0-9]` section... I match it with that regex right there!

But I don't know how to preserve the values AND remove the space. Replacing it wholesale with new stuff, sure... but how do I PRESERVE values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Find what:** `(\d)\s(\d)$`

**Replace with:** `thread\1\2`

`\d` matches any digit, `\s` matches any space character.

The parentheses will be captured for use as `\1`, `\2`, `\3`... and `\0` will provide the entire match.*

`$` matches the end of a line, so that you don't accidentally match the "5 0" in the first line.

*Note that some regex engines use the `\1` pattern while some others will use `$1`. Notepad++ uses the former.

Comment: Glad I could help. If your format deviates at all, such as having more than one digit, check out @scrowler's answer for some more advanced stuff. This is the bare minimum.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

**Pattern:**

```
/^(.*)(\d+)\s(\d+)$/
```

Breakdown:

```
^       # start of line
(.*)    # the first part of the line      -- capture $1
(\d+)   # the first number (1 or more)    -- capture $2
\s      # the space between the numbers
(\d+)   # the second number (1 or more)   -- capture $3
$       # end of line
```

**Replace:**

```
/$1thread$2$3/
```

**Result:**

```
Time: 105 thread00
Time: 88  thread01
Time: 44  thread11
Time: 64  thread10
```

**Demo**: http://regex101.com/r/gB8uS4